# How to test a multithreaded webserver written in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, webserver

I am implementing a multi-threaded webserver using python. I have read some web server example code such as the ones here:
[Multithreaded web server in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088294/multithreaded-web-server-in-python)

But once the server is setup on my machine, how should I test if it is a multithreaded server?

Thanks,